# Error when trying to generate a report with jasperReports barcode with spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, jasper-reports

I'm trying to generate a report with a barcode using jasperResports, but it gives this error:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
org/apache/batik/bridge/UserAgent
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/batik/bridge/UserAgent
    at net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.util.RendererUtil.getSvgDataSniffer(RendererUtil.java:164)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.util.RendererUtil.getSvgInfo(RendererUtil.java:133)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.util.RendererUtil.isSvgData(RendererUtil.java:114)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.util.RendererUtil.isSvgData(RendererUtil.java:153)
    at...
```

remembering this error when I add the barcode4j barcode

I researched it and saw that I had to add this dependency in Maven's .POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
    <artifactId>batik-bridge</artifactId>
    <version>1.11</version>
</dependency>
```

my complete .pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>3.1.5</version>
       <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>br.com.desktop</groupId>
    <artifactId>deskestoque</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>deskestoque</name>
    <description>projeto estoque</description>
    <properties>
       <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
       <!-- spring boot core -->
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
       </dependency>

       <!-- spring data and JPA -->
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
       </dependency>


       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
          <optional>true</optional>
       </dependency>

       <!-- MySQL JDBC connector -->

       <dependency>
          <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
          <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
       </dependency>

       <!-- MariaDB JDBC connector -->
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
          <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
       </dependency>

       <!-- Lombok -->
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
          <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
          <optional>true</optional>
       </dependency>

       <!-- POJO Mapper -->
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
          <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.4</version>
       </dependency>

       <!-- JasperReports  -->
       <dependency>
          <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
          <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
          <version>6.20.0</version>
       </dependency>

       <!--  commons -->
       <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.1</version>
       </dependency>
       <!--  barcode4j -->
       <dependency>
          <groupId>com.singingbush</groupId>
          <artifactId>barcode4j</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.1</version>
       </dependency>

       <!--  barbecue -->
       <dependency>
          <groupId>net.sourceforge.barbecue</groupId>
          <artifactId>barbecue</artifactId>
          <version>1.5-beta1</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
          <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
          <version>RELEASE</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
       </dependency>


       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
          <artifactId>batik-bridge</artifactId>
          <version>1.11</version>
       </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
       <plugins>
          <plugin>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             <configuration>
                <image>
                   <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                </image>
             </configuration>
          </plugin>
       </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
       <repository>
          <id>Maven Central</id>
          <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
       </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

But you still get the error, does anyone know what it could be?

I'm trying to generate a PDF of a report but I'm having this problem, if anyone knows a solution or something to help I'd appreciate it, I've been looking for a solution for a long time...